# Adding Data to Firebase from RaspberryPi button click

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi

As the title says I'm trying to add data to my cloud firestore through a button click from my raspberry pi button clicker using Python. I have managed to made it worked but if i click the button more than once it would not add the data into my database again unless rerun my script again. Meaning if i click the button once it would add to the database but if i click again it doesn't add anything but the "add" does appear.

```
new_doc = db.collection(u'report').document()

#YELLOW 
greenBtn = Button(17) #Using gpiozero library
greenLED = LED(13)


def add():
    greenLED.on()
    try:
        new_doc.set({u'name': u'report two'})
        print("add")
    except:
        print("fail")

greenBtn.when_pressed = add
greenBtn.when_released = greenLED.off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new document the first time the script runs. Then when the user presses the button, you keep updating that same document. So while each click of the button causes a write, you don't see subsequent writes since you're writing the same value to the same document all the time.

Two solutions:

1. Write a different value each time
2. Write to a different document each time.

Since you seem to expect a new document, I'll show how to do that:

```
#YELLOW 
greenBtn = Button(17) #Using gpiozero library
greenLED = LED(13)


def add():
    greenLED.on()
    new_doc = db.collection(u'report').document()

    try:
        new_doc.set({u'name': u'report two'})
```

So the creation of the new document now happens each time the user presses the button.

Comment: Thank you sir, did not take into account that i was actually modifying the value instead of writing a new document